# Проверка на четырехугольник в Prolog

Tags: prolog, геометрия

Здравствуйте! Подскажите, пожалуйста, как определить является ли введенные точки четырехугольником.

Есть факты следующего вида:

> точка( 1, 1).
> точка( 1, 2).
> точка( 1, 3).
> точка( 1, 4).
> точка( 2, 2).

Какое условие должно выполняться, чтобы понимать введены вершины четырехугольника или нет здесь:

> четырехугольник( точка( X1, Y1), точка( X2, Y2), точка( X3, Y3), точка( X4, Y4)) :- **?**

По большому счету геометрия это.

Comment: Проверяете, что три точки, напр 1, 2, 3 или 1, 2, 4 не лежат на одной прямой. Ну и что любые две точки не совпадают.

Comment: а как проверить написали бы.

Answer (score 1):

там навернека был и треугольник в задаче.

На линию тоже проверка

```
line(tochka(X1,Y1),tochka(X2,Y2)):-not(X1=X2),not(Y1=Y2).

tr(line1,line2,line3):-P=(a+b+c)/2, S=sqrt(P*(P-a)*(P-b)*(P-c)),not(S=0) площадь

rect(line1,line2,line3,line4):-tr(line1,line2,line3),tr(line2,line3,line4).
```

Площадь четырехугольника не ноль.

Я бы так сделал.

Comment: 1. Для эффективного вычисления площади лучше воспользоваться (псевдо)векторным произведением.
2. Ваш код не охватывает, например, случай, когда вершины 1, 3 и 4 лежат на одной прямой.

Comment: кстати, да, а добавить tr(line3,line4,line1) или это неправильно будет?